# How do I subtract from numbers over a 122?

Tags: c#, loops, encryption, integer, caesar-cipher

I have a bunch of user inputted integers assigned to a variable 'c,' and am trying to subtract from the values over 122. I've tried a load of different loops, but I usually get stuck with it not working or taking 90 away from all of them. So how exactly do I take 90 away from numbers over 122, anyway?

(this is for a caesar shift encryption program, 122 being lower-case 'z' in ASCII)

```
        List<int> valerie = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 32; i < 122; i++)
        {
            valerie.Add(i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("E - Encrypt");
        Console.WriteLine("D - Decrypt");

        string choice = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (choice.ToUpper())
        {
            case "E":


                Console.WriteLine("Enter Caesar shift.");
                string shift = Console.ReadLine();
                int offset = int.Parse(shift);
                Console.WriteLine("Enter phrase.");
                string phrase = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(phrase);
                foreach(byte b in asciiBytes)
                { 
                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(b);
                    int c = a + offset;
                    Console.WriteLine(c);
                    char d = (char)c;
                    Console.WriteLine(d);
                }
```

Comment: Which part of you code is supposed to do this check? Bascally you need: `if(c > 122) { c -= 90; }`

Comment: so you just want it to work over `A`-`Z` right? You don't have to decode it at all then - just *subtract* `'A'` (`var n = (int)(c - 'A')`) and then use `%` (finally converting back with `(char)` and `+ 'A'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use *modular* arithmetics: not just add a `offset` to each character, but take a *remainder*, so with a help of the *Linq* you can put it:

```
 int offset = ...
 String phrase = ...;

 // Providing that the phrase constains 'A'..'z' ard/or 'a'..'z' only
 String encoded = new String(phrase
   .Select(ch => (Char) (ch <= 'Z' ? 
            (ch + offset) % 26 + 'A' : // note "% 26"
            (ch + offset) % 26 + 'a')) // note "% 26"
   .ToArray());
```

Comment: @Dmytro Shevchenko: thank you! I've edited the typo.

Comment: Kudos for calling it the remainder operator instead of the modulus operator

Answer (score 0):

Either I misunderstood your question, or you just need to check your input...

```
//Version 1
int c = a;
if(a > 122)
    c = c - offset;

//Version 2, more compact
int c = a > 122 ? a : a + offset;
```